# Sort Related List according Boolean formula field

Tags: related-list, sort

In my account page I present all the account products.

Each product object has custom boolean filed - formula type.
This formula calculate if the product license is valid or not.

In the GUI - there is no way to sort the products base on this formula filed.

Is there any way to sort the related list using code?

Comment: Isn't there? You should just be able to edit the page layout, add the field to the related list (under the "columns" header), and then select that in the "Sort By" picklist (also under the "columns" header), no?

Comment: Nope - this one is not possible. also opened ticket within SF regarding this issue but they declare it as a bug which will solved in the future..
So I'm looking for a way to sort the list using APEX (if possible)